# JavaFX MediaPlayer - seek() method makes the player hang

Tags: javafx

I've been looking for ages for direction on this matter and I finally post here.

I have a JavaFX application with MediaPlayer. One day, seeking at a later position in video (that had not been accessed previously) started hanging the player. No status change before it gets to PLAYING, the buffer is loaded, status at READY before I call seek().

First I thought it is because I went out of Application thread, tried to put the MediaPlayer back on the root to be sure, and the seek method worked as before, fast enough for me. 
But then for a reason I can't get, it started hanging again all the time, with same symptoms.
Now, even with the most simple code, it hangs too.

I'm desperate, the waiting time can be 30 seconds to reach a position 2 minutes later in the video. Looks like the Media Player is scanning again all video until it finds the good position it's seeking, thus taking more time for a later position. If the position has been accessed before though, seek() won't hang...

Am I the only one with this problem?

I'm on Mac os EL Capitan, but tried on Windows VM too and I get the same behaviour.

Here is a standalone code, but I don't see how it will help, I don't even hope for ppl to reproduce:

```
public class VideoPlayerExample extends Application {
public static void main(String[] args) throws Exception {
    launch(args);
}

@Override
public void start(final Stage stage) throws Exception {

    File file = new FileChooser().showOpenDialog(stage);
    Media media = new Media(file.toURI().toString());
    MediaPlayer mp = new MediaPlayer(media);
    mp.statusProperty().addListener(new ChangeListener<MediaPlayer.Status>() {
        @Override
        public void changed(ObservableValue<? extends Status> observable, Status oldValue, Status newValue) {
            System.out.println(newValue);
        }
    });

    Group gp = new Group(new MediaView(mp));

    Button buttonTest = new Button("It's gonna hang...");
    buttonTest.setOnAction(new EventHandler<ActionEvent>() {
        @Override
        public void handle(ActionEvent event) {
            mp.pause();
            System.out.println(mp.getCurrentTime().toMillis());
            mp.seek(new Duration(mp.getCurrentTime().toMillis() +10000));

            mp.play();
        }
    });

    gp.getChildren().add(buttonTest);
    stage.setScene(new Scene(gp, 540, 208));
    stage.show();
}
}
```

Any help will be so greatly appreciated!

Answer (score 0):

You're right - I can't reproduce your problem.  I have macOS Sierra 10.12.6.  All I can say is check the type of movie you're trying to play - not all encodings are supported.  Also, according to the documentation, if the movie's duration is Duration.INDEFINITE, seek() will have no effect.

Answer (score 0):

Place the seek method in a new thread not on your JavaFX thread.

```
new Thread(() -> mp.seek(new Duration(mp.getCurrentTime().toMillis() +10000)))).start();
```